# My windows 10 computer won't recognize a gaming headset

Tags: laptop, gaming, acer-aspire, headset

I have an Acer aspire vx laptop with a single 3.5 mm combo (audio/mic) jack, I just bought a Corsair hs35 headset to use but when I plug it in the mic on the headset won't work. I can hear very quiet audio through the headset so my computer knows there's something plugged in but the mic is non existent. I've tried looking in my device manager to set it as the default but the headset doesn't show up in the device manager so there's nothing I can fiddle with or adjust. Any help would be much appreciated because I'm at the point where I'm ready to throw something out the window, thanks.

Comment: try it on your phone

Comment: it works perfectly on my phone, I can't get it to work on my computer

Comment: maybe your laptop does not allow the plug to be fully inserted

Answer (score 0):

Update, I solved my problem by changing the answer to the prompt that showed when I plug something into my 3.5mm jack from "headset" to "speaker"